# WordPress include wp-load.php --> Error 500

Tags: php, wordpress, require

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I have a problem, every time I try to require wp-load.php in my PHP Script (Outside of Wordpress), I will get a Error 500 (Internal Server Error), what I want to do is that https://stackoverflow.com/a/19677968/9544599, and it worked yestarday. If I remove

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-load.php");
```

I still get the Error, but if I remove

```
$string29 = wp_check_password($password, $array4['user_pass']);
```

and replace it with

```
$string29 = true;
```

it works. (It also gives out an Error if i remove just the Function).

And enabeling any of the Log options from PHP (display_errors, display_startup_errors, log_errors) and WP_DEBUG I still get only Error 500.

And everything on the first page of Google don't worked for me.

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Sorry fore my bad English btw.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer myself, but I'am not sure why that was the Error.
In the same PHP File, I have a funtion called discord($message) and maby the function was occupied. I have changed the Name of the funtion to discordmsg($message) and all worked.